# C++ library for calculating arithmetic expressions with radicals

Tags: c++, numeric, symbolic-math

I would like to do lengthy numerical calculations that include rational numbers and square roots. Is there a C++ library that can make these calculations without calculating the numerical value of radicals and can reduce the expression? For example, I want to calculate eigenvalues of an integer matrix `{{1,2},{3,4}}`. I want the answer in a form `{1/2 * (5 + sqrt(33)), 1/2 * (5 - sqrt(33))}`.

I know there are generic libraries for symbolic calculations like GiNaC, but it seems like an overkill. I believe non generic calculations just over rational numbers with radicals can be more efficient.

Comment: what about http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/symbolic.html ?

Comment: It looks very interesting, I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: It's similar to GiNaC, right? It feels like an overkill for what I need. I'll use if I don't find something more specific. I don't need algebra variables, just rational numbers and radicals.

Comment: Yes, it is similar to GiNaC, but better made and with better documentation I believe - you could by a book. And probably better with rationals. `I'll use if I don't find something more specific. I don't need algebra variables, just rational numbers and radicals.` That's probably a bit of a wrong argument - if you don't use it, where is the harm? If won't even be paged in into program address space

Comment: More specific version can be faster than a general full-blown symbolic algebraic system. Or it's not true with regard to SymbolicC++?

Comment: Mmm... That's not given, and (trying to remember what I've learned about it - it was quite some time ago) it shouldn't be true